# Spring AOP pointcut by declared return type

Tags: java, aop, spring-aop

I have the following class and methods:

```
public class Hello {
    public String getGreetingA() {
        return "hello";
    }
    public boolean getGreetingB() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And the following Aspect:

```
@Aspect
public class HelloAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution (public String Hello.*(..)")
    public void pointcut() {}

    @Around("pointcut")
    public Object advice(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
        // do something...
        Object result = pjp.proceed;
        // do something...
        return result;
    }
}
```

Currently, the advice is executed for both the `Hello` class methods.
I want the aspect to only target methods that return `String` type. It seems The `execution` pointcut is not that relevant here (as the advice is of `Around` type, and the return value does not yet exist when the advice is executed).

Is There a simple why in Spring AOP to define a pointcut to target on Joinpoints that their declared return value is of certain type?

(I know i can get the `pjp.proceed` return value and check its `instance of`, but i would like to refrain from that)

Comment: The pattern that you have for `@Pointcut` now should only work for method `getGreetingA` since it matches all public methods in `Hello` with a return type of `String`.

Answer (score 1):

I have copied your classes and as expected the aspect only work for getGreetingA, i'am not able to reproduce your case where both of them are targeted

There are some syntax error in your example, here is correct code :

```
 @Pointcut("execution (public String Hello.*(..))")
 @Around("pointcut()")
```